# Save Excel file as text with Tab delimited without ignoring empty rows at begin

Tags: vba, excel

After run Macro on my Excel file (.xlsx) I have output like this:

[image]

With 3 first empty columns for each row.

Then when I try to save this as Text with Tab delimited I got output (.txt) but without 3 first empty rows:

[image]

Others empty rows was displayed properly as tabulation, but these 3 first rows was somehow deleted. But in my case I need this.

Any solution how to avoid that situation? Adding it manually don't be a soltuion, because I have huge amounts of data.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this, to see if it works: http://excel.tips.net/T003068_Inconsistent_Output_for_Empty_Columns_in_a_CSV_File.html

Comment: Thanks. For now I do it with input empty string (" ") into this first three rows and then save. It's helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the First Row of First 3 Columns enter any dummy special character like "#".

Example:

## #   #   # 1 999 999 2   10  3

Just enter these # symbols in first ROW. and now save the excel as Tab delimited text file. I get output as below.

Output:

## #   #   # 1 999 999 2   10  3

```
        1   999 999 2   10  3
        1   999 999 2   10  3
        1   999 999 2   10  3
```

Hope this solves the problem in this case. If the empty rows or columns are not consistent, then the code present in Alex page can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Put a formula in the last columns of rows that are empty that evaluate to empty (e.g. =""). And then export.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by adding the following line before save.

Columns("A:A").NumberFormatLocal = "@"